# NTier logic layers with models, handling CRUD

Tags: c#, .net, n-tier-architecture

NTier logic layers with models, handling CRUD

My team is looking at rearchitecting some of our system to meet the following pattern

- Data Layer (Entity Framework backed, database-first)
- Models (POCOS, not same models as in DAL)
- Logic Layer (references to Data Layer and Models)
- ASP.NET Presentation

We have some Models like:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Make { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Configuration> AvailableConfigurations { get; set; }
}
```

In the logic layer we have a CarLogic class like

```
public interface ICarLogic
{
   void Add(Car);
   void Update(Car);
   void Delete(Car);
   void GetAll(Car);
   void GetByManufacturer(ManfacturerId);
}
```

Database schema

Table `Car`
Columns: Id, Model

Table: Configuration
Columns: Id, Description

Table: Manufacturer
Columns: Id, Description

Table: Car_Configs
Columns: Car_Id_Fk, Configuration_Id_Fk

So now for the questions,

1. When calling the Update on the implementor of ICarLogic, should each property such as AvailableConfigurations be checked to see what does not exist in the database and needs to be added, what is on the database and not in the IEnumberable that should be deleted then do all the table updates from there?
2. Should we sub out READ queries like shown, GetAll, GetByManufacturer, etc. because many of our models will have several, then do we get into GetAllWithConfigurationsAnd.... GetByManufacturer, GetByManufacturerWithConfigurations, or just always include the properties even though some models will have up to 10 joins when that information isn't even needed by the caller?

Comment: Personally I don't like the specification of a multitude of methods such as GetByManufacturer etc. The problem is they expand and grow and become unmanageable. Also do you want to restrict users to the filters you provide. I prefer creating a 'query' object which leverages data source metadata and has a filters collection

Answer (score 0):

That could be a good example where the [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) design model fits better.

Regarding your questions:

1) I would personally split the Update into: an update the basic attributes of Car, and methods to add/update/remove configurations for a given car individually. This is basically to avoid checking each time what has been changed for all the available configurations.

2) I'll definetely create the minimum READ queries needed for the viewmodel in question only.

Comment: What would you do for validation? We were thinking a validate function on the view model that returns an IEnumberable of error objects and on the logic layer if you try to perform an operation in the logic on an invalid model then it throws a validation exception.

Comment: and if that's good should it check each IEnumerable of different models as well or run each individually?

Comment: You mean an IEnumerable to hold all the validation errors for the available configurations of your car, if any?? I tend to wrap those validation messages in a really simple class like public class AjaxResult { public bool Success {get;set;} public string ErrorMessage { get;set; } }